# How to get list of members of enum from Custom Attribute?

Tags: c#, enums, custom-attributes

I have:

(1)Types enum like:

```
public enum Types : int
{
[ParametrizedContentTypeAttribute(typeOf(Type1ParamEnum))]
Type1 = 10,

[ParametrizedContentTypeAttribute(typeOf(Type2ParamEnum))]
Type2 = 20,

[ParametrizedContentTypeAttribute(typeOf(Type3ParamEnum))]
Type3 = 30
}
```

(2)Parameters enums

```
public enum Type1ParamEnum : int
{
Type1Param1 = 10,
Type1Param2 = 20,
Type1Param3 = 30
}

public enum Type2ParamEnum : int
{
Type2Param1 = 10,
Type2Param2 = 20,
Type2Param3 = 30
}

public enum Type3ParamEnum : int
{
Type3Param1 = 10,
Type3Param2 = 20,
Type3Param3 = 30
}
```

(3)Custom attribute

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
    public class ParametrizedContentTypeAttribute : DescriptionAttribute
    {
        public ParametrizedContentTypeAttribute(Type parametersType)
        {
            ParametersType = parametersType;
        }

        public Type ParametersType { get; private set; }
    }
```

How to get the list of available members of Enums from 2. if I know the Id of Types enum member from 1. ?

Comment: what do the id types of 1 (what do you mean here?) have to do with 2 (guessing u mean Type2ParamEnum)? You can get an enums values with [enum.GetValues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getvalues.aspx)

Comment: "types of 1" - means types from (2)Parameters Enums

Comment: Enums are only values, ints really. Are you trying to define a two-dimensional enum?

Comment: Exactly! Something like: having Id of first enum member I can get the list of second, third ... etc

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it can be faked by using classes, like in Java.
The names are crappy and the resulting values overlap, so you'll have to figure something out to calculate them properly, but this should get you started:

```
// Example model
public enum enumBuilding { Hotel, House, Skyscraper };
public enum enumFloor { Basement, GroundFloor, Penthouse };
public enum enumRoom { Entry, Office, Toilet };

public abstract class EnumArray
{
    static protected Building[] buildings;

    static EnumArray()
    {
        buildings = new Building[Enum.GetValues(typeof(enumBuilding)).Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < buildings.Length; i++)
            buildings[i] = new Building(i);
    }

    public static Building Hotel { get { return buildings[0]; } }
    public static Building House { get { return buildings[1]; } }
    public static Building Skyscraper { get { return buildings[2]; } }
}

public class Building
{
    protected Floor[] floors;

    public Building(int start)
    {
        floors = new Floor[Enum.GetValues(typeof(enumFloor)).Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < floors.Length; i++)
            floors[i] = new Floor(start + i * floors.Length);
    }

    public Floor Basement { get { return floors[0]; } }
    public Floor GroundFloor { get { return floors[1]; } }
    public Floor Penthouse { get { return floors[2]; } }
}

public class Floor
{
    protected int[] rooms;

    public Floor(int start)
    {
        rooms = new int[Enum.GetValues(typeof(enumRoom)).Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < rooms.Length; i++)
            rooms[i] = new Room(start + i * rooms.Length);
    }

    public int Entry { get { return rooms[0]; } }
    public int Office { get { return rooms[1]; } }
    public int Toilet { get { return rooms[2]; } }
}

        var index = EnumArray.Hotel.Basement.Office;
```